# Alembic does not recognize the default schema when creating initial migrations

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm at my wits end here. I'm trying to create an initial migration to my Postgres database using alembic. I'm autogenerating the migration from my SQLAlchemy ORM models.

Here's my `models.py` file:

```
from typing import List, Optional

from sqlalchemy import Boolean, ForeignKey, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

from myapp.database.core import Base, TimestampMixin

from .choices import RoleChoices


class Company(TimestampMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = "companies"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    domain: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(128), unique=True)
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=True)
    users: Mapped[List["User"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="company", cascade="all, delete-orphan", passive_deletes=True
    )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"""
        <Company(
            id={self.id},
            name={self.name},
            domain={self.domain},
            is_active={self.id})>"""


class User(TimestampMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(128), unique=True)
    username: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(128))
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=True)
    role: Mapped[RoleChoices]
    company_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey("companies.id", ondelete="CASCADE")
    )
    company: Mapped["Company"] = relationship(back_populates="users")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<User(id={self.id}, email={self.email}, username={self.username})>"
```

My base model is:

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class TimestampMixin:
    created_at: Mapped[DateTime] = mapped_column(
        DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow
    )
    updated_at: Mapped[DateTime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=True)
```

My `alembic.ini` file is the autogenerated file when running `alembic init migrations`, so I haven't edited at all.

My `env.py` file inside the `migrations` folder looks like this:

```
import os
from logging.config import fileConfig

from alembic import context
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool

from myapp.auth.models import Company, User  # noqa
from myapp.database.core import Base

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

DB_USER = os.environ.get("DB_USER")
DB_NAME = os.environ.get("DB_NAME")
DB_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD")
DB_HOST = os.environ.get("DB_HOST")
DB_PORT = os.environ.get("DB_PORT")

connection_string = (
    f"postgresql+psycopg2://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"
)

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", connection_string)

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Finally the way I setup my database is via docker, but I have the commands in my Makefile:

```
.PHONY: db-create db-start db-stop db-remove db-drop-extensions db-init

db-create:
    @echo "Creating database container..."
    docker run --name $(DB_CONTAINER_NAME) -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(DB_PASSWORD) -d postgres

db-start:
    @echo "Starting database container..."
    docker start postgres

db-stop:
    @echo "Stopping database container..."
    docker stop postgres

db-remove:
    @echo "Removing database container..."
    docker rm postgres

db-init: db-create db-start
    @echo "Initialising database..."
    sleep 10

db-teardown: db-stop db-remove
```

Oh and for the purpose of testing my `env.py` looks like this:

```
export DB_NAME="postgres"
export DB_USER="postgres"
export DB_PASSWORD="postgres"
export DB_HOST="localhost"
export DB_PORT="5432"
export DB_CONTAINER_NAME="postgres"
```

After I run `source .env` I then execute the following make command `make db-init`. After which this gets printed to my terminal:

```
Creating database container...
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres
f32873ec9faf9c09bd0ea1e5ff1247dadd60c3eb0ed82b63a318813b27ca783f
Starting database container...
docker start postgres
postgres
Initialising database...
sleep 10
```

Now I have my database container up and running.

Finally when I try to run an alembic revision like `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "add company and user models"` I get the following error message:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/my-app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1965, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/myuser/my-app/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 921, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName: no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
...
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
                     ^

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
        version_num VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT alembic_version_pkc PRIMARY KEY (version_num)
)

]
```

What's going on here? It seems like Alembic doesn't have access to the right schema, but on the other hand I haven't explicitly set a schema so I'm under the impression that alembic should default to the `public` schema of postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel kind of dumb right now. The issue was that I had the postgres.app application open on my Mac at the same time with my Postgres database in docker. It seemed like alembic was connecting to that version of postgres.

After I closed the app, the migrations worked fine.